# Get a list of the absolute paths of all the images in a page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Could someone show me how to get a list of aboslute paths for all the images in a webpage using BeautifulSoup?

It's simple to get all the images. I'm doing this:

```
page_images = [image["src"] for image in soup.findAll("img")]
```

...but I'm having difficulties getting the absolute paths. Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to normalize the paths after getting them. This can be done using [`urlparse.urljoin`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin). For example:

```
>>> urlparse.urljoin("http://google.com/some/path/", "../../img/icon.png")
'http://google.com/img/icon.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not using BeautifulSoup, but the more elegant (and well-maintained) lxml+[pyquery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/):

```
import pyquery
from urlparse import urljoin

def make_images_absolute(self):
    self('img').each(lambda: self(this).attr('src',
           urljoin(self.base_url, self(this).attr('src'))))

url="http://lwn.net"
pq = pyquery.PyQuery(url)
for i in pq("img"):
    print i.attrib["src"]
make_images_absolute(pq)
for i in pq("img"):
    print i.attrib["src"]
```